# infinispan CLI cache does not liist all cache names

Tags: caching, infinispan

I am trying to use infinispan CLI to remove a key from cache.
Once i connect I get the prompt with the default cache manager

As per the documentation , when I type cache and tab out , the list  of cache names will be printed. But It does not happen . I get the below printed in the console.

org.infinispan.cli.interpreter.Interpreter.createSessionId()

None of the commands are working as per the documentation. May  be i am missing some steps . Has any one faced such issue ?

I am using infinispan 5.2

Thanks

lives

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried latest Infinispan community release 7.0.3?

Comment: No - Since commercial JDG support is not available for 7 , we are using 5.2

Comment: Hmmm, well, if using JDG you should be directing the question to professional where the question can be better handled.